# OPENCL warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'float __global[16]' to parameter of type '__global float4 *

Tags: c++, casting, opencl

I am defining a structure in C++, built a vector in a loop and created its buffer using clCreateBuffer() function, which is then passed to my CL kernel. My kernel code calls funcA where the buffer is passed as an argument. I am then using the buffer and calling funcB giving array as an argument.

```
    typedef struct a {
        float array[16];
        unsigned int id;
    } BUFFER_TYPE;

    float RD_INLINE funcB(__global float4* m)
    {
      ..
    }

    bool RD_INLINE funcA(__global BUFFER_TYPE* buffer)
   {
      ..
      float scale = funcB(buffer[0].array);
      ..
   }
```

I am getting " warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'float __global[16]' to parameter of type '__global float4 *'". How do I resolve this? How can I typecast here?

Comment: `(__global float4*)buffer[0].array` should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

For `float4` the array should be of 4 elements: `float array[4]`. You could use `cl_float4` from `CL/cl_platform.h` which will define that properly for you. 
See more about OpenCL vector types [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/vectorDataTypes.html).

If the warning still persists then you will need to define your struct in cl file too using `float4` instead of `float array[4]` or `cl_float4`.

Comment: `float[4]` is not the same as `float4` (`cl_float4` in host). A pointer to `float[4]` decays to a pointer of `float`, which is not interchangeable with a pointer to `float4`.